# how to create a excel function that returns an array of variable size

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a excel function that returns the result of a sql query. 
I can do it if the result has size 1x1. However if the result is larger than that, I could not make the code work. Is there a solution for that? I am especially struggling with the fact that in all examples I have found, it is required to select exactly the right number of cells, whereas the result of my sql query could be of any size... and changing through time.

here is what I use so far:

```
Public Function getTS(field As String) As String
        Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        Dim oRecordset As ADOR.Recordset
        oConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=AISDB;Data Source=mydomainlocation\mydatabase;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"
        Set oRecordset = oConnection.Execute("select " & field & " from mytable where country = 'China'")
        If oRecordset.EOF Then
            getTS = "n/a"
        Else
            getTS = oRecordset(field)
        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - sorry, I thought you were writing the function to return values to a vba subroutine. If you want a UDF you'll have to return a variant array and in the spreadsheet enter it as an array formula across the appropriate number of cells. Which means you'll have to know how many rows will be returned in advance.

```
 Public Function getTS(fieldnames As String) As variant

Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRecordset As ADOR.Recordset
oConnection.Open....
Set oRecordset = ....
Dim x as long
 dim y as long
 y = 1
redim A(rs.fields.count,1)
do while not rs.eof
 For x = 1 to rs.fields.count
      A(x,y)=rs(x)
  Next x
 Rs.movenext
y = y+1
Redim preserve A(rs.fields.count,y+1)
Loop
rs.close
GetTS = A()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the recordset itself

```
Public Function getTS(field As String) As Recordset
    Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordset As ADOR.Recordset
    oConnection.Open....
    Set oRecordset = ....
    Set GetTS = oRecordset
End Function
```

and then put the result into cells by specifying only the top left cell using

```
  Activesheet.range("a2").CopyFromRecordset GetTS("myField")
```

Comment: should I input `=Activesheet.range("a2").CopyFromRecordset GetTS("myField")` ? I get a popup with `There's a problem with your formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the character is an equal (=) or minus (-), Excel thinks it is a formula [...]`